# Openvz and Telegraf

Tags: influxdb, openvz, telegraf

I need to monitor `OpenVZ` containers using `TICK` stack. But it must be done without install anything inside of containers. Is there any plugins for `Telegraf` to collect metric (cpu, bandwidth, iops) from `OpenVZ` container?

Answer (score 1):

OpenVZ is deprecated since long time. Try this new thing named Docker, or at least LXC.

Telegraf uses cgroups for collecting metrics from containers, Docker, LXC use cgroups.